# PinCode block the OS while application are running

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was on a Windows 8 dev camp few days ago. I have a fragment of memory that some of the speakers told that W8 give the possibility to require pincode interaction to allow a exit of the running application. Am I right here?

Exit in this case mean that the environment, except the application itself, is completely blocked until correct pincode are entered. I see it as a good fit for kid application but also to easify lending out phone/tab.

This should be an established question, today?